# How to yii2 addError for array[key]

Tags: arrays, validation, yii2, key

```
public function beforeValidate() {

    if(isset($this->detailsData[5]) && !$this->detailsData[5]){
        $this->addError('detailsData[5]', 'error msg');
        return false;
    }

    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

I am trying to show error msg on a particular array key in ActiveForm

Comment: try remove `return false;` in your code, and check without array index to if your code is correct and problem is in array index or in your code

Comment: tried that `$this->addError('detailsData', 'error msg');`  by removing key the msg is applied to all fields

Comment: Maybe try defining the function like this **public function beforeValidate($attribute, $model) {**  and create the error like this **$this->addError($attribute, 'error msg');**

Comment: Please mention your definition of $this->detailsData[5]